# Copy file bug on OneDrive (REST API)

Tags: javascript, api, copy, onedrive

I have been using for long time the copy request action as described here:
(https://dev.onedrive.com/items/copy.htm) - 
POST /drive/items/{item-id}/copy?access_token=...
(There is a small bug however, as it is a little bit different: POST /drive/items/{item-id}/action.copy?access_token=...) is the correct one.

From the Copy - POST request I was getting a url from Location response header: https:// onedrive.com/monitor/{monitor-id-...} to monitor the copy progress and when the status was completed, there was a response with the metadata of the new resource (e.g data.id, name, createdTime etc). I was doing a GET url request to get all these monitor details.

2 days ago I noticed there are some differences on the response of the API.

- The url has a different format https://onedrive.com/monitor/{monitor-id-...}?access_token=..... When I am trying to make a GET using the url, I am receiving an ***API not found*** message.
- When I am removing the access_token from the url and doing the GET request again, the new response is 200, but it is missing the data response with information about the newly created item.

To solve that issue, I need to getItem for the new item and get the metadata which adds more requests and more time for the copy action.
Any ideas why/ what happened exactly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**
This issue should now be resolved.

**Original**
This looks like a newly introduced bug in the service - as long as auth is provided the request to the monitor to 303 to a valid URL for the created resource. What's happening in this case appears to be a redirect to an invalid URL:

`https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drives('me')/items('')?access_token=foo`

We'll work on getting this fixed ASAP.

Comment: @Brad Hi bro, the api "/drive/items/{item-id}/copy" is still not working, why this wrong api is still in developer guide page?
Link here: https://dev.onedrive.com/items/copy.htm

Comment: Issue seems to start happening again.